# I want to create pods with custom ordinal index in stateful set

Tags: kubernetes, containers, openshift, devops, statefulset

Currently when I apply stateful set then pods are getting created with ab-app-0, ab-app-1 , ab-app-2

But I want pods like ab-app-1000, ab-app-1001

Answer (score 1):

The [Kubernetes documentation on StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#ordinal-index) says the following about ordinal index:

> For a StatefulSet with N replicas, each Pod in the StatefulSet will be assigned an integer ordinal, from 0 up through N-1, that is unique over the Set.

So there looks to be no way of customising this. But if your concern is that you need to pass this unique ID to a service, you could do the following in the config file, as proposed in [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40651) open github issue:

```yaml
        env:
        - name: ZOO_MY_ID
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.annotations['spec.pod.beta.kubernetes.io/statefulset-index']
```

Comment: I believe this is no longer true. Kubernetes now supports customizing the start index, and the only available annotation for StatefulSet-driven pods (per [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/labels-annotations-taints/#labels-annotations-and-taints-used-on-api-objects)) is the resulting pod name.

Answer (score 0):

A new feature landed as a beta in v1.27, allowing you to customize the ordinal index `.spec.ordinals.start`. Please check the official documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#start-ordinal).